# Trained SVM has 0 percent training accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

I am training an SVM on some EEG data for speech recognition purposes. I am trying to do a binary classification of the data points. This is the code for training my SVM.

```
rbf_clf = svm.SVC()
param_grid = {"C": [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 1.5],
            "gamma": [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10],
            "kernel": ['linear', 'rbf', 'sigmoid', 'poly'],
            "decision_function_shape": ['ovo'],
            }
grid_cv = GridSearchCV(rbf_clf, param_grid=param_grid, cv=4, refit=True, n_jobs=4, pre_dispatch=8)
grid_cv.fit(training_features, training_labels)
rbf_clf = grid_cv.best_estimator_
rbf_clf.fit(training_features, training_labels)
prediction = rbf_clf.predict(training_features)
print(prediction)
print(testing_labels)
print(rbf_clf.decision_function(training_features))
```

As an experimente, I tried doing the prediction on the training_features and I was expecting a perfect classification, since that is the data the classifier was trained on. However, the output of the prediction was a vector of all 0's. Does anyone know why this could be happening? Or could anyone have a hint on where I could look at to solve this issue or what am I missing? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by `"the output of the prediction was a vector of all 0's"`? Maybe the training data has labels 0, which the model is correctly predicting?

Answer (score 0):

Try shuffling your data. It is possible that for your train and test split, all the training examples belong to class 0 and thus your classifier learns that regardless of the input features, always output 0.